# Charging a device with higher amperage, can somebody please clear up the confusion and contradictory statements?

Tags: voltage, batteries, battery-charging, charger, amperage

I have a PS Vita I wish to charge with my Samsung Galaxy charger, its output is 9.0V = 1.57A which is for fast charging (correct me if I'm wrong) and thus won't handshake with the Vita so won't supply this power (again, correct me if I'm wrong)  or 5.0V = 2.0A
The regular charger for the Fat PSVITA supplies 5V = 1000mA and the regular charger for the Slim PSVITA supplies 5V = 1500mA.
I posted a question on Amazon asking if I could charge the PSVita with a Samsung Galaxy charger because as far as I know it would only supply the amperage the system asks for and someone replied saying this:

> This is only partially accurate.  The PSV has the capacity to play while charging which normally just makes the device charge more
>   slowly. Using a higher capacity would mitagate this a bit, but for
>   standard charging it would charge the battery to quickly causing
>   overheating and decreased life span for the battery. It would also
>   lead to battery expansion (ballooning).

He had me worried a little bit, but as far as I know and according to other sources online as long as the amperage of the charger is higher than the amperage the device needs and not lower it should be perfectly fine, but maybe he is still right and charging it with a Galaxy charger would make the battery expand, overheat and have a decreased lifespan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, the Samsung’s Adaptive Fast Charging is a sort of Quick Charge 2.0, and therefore requires a QC-type "negotiation" to output potentially damaging 9-V charging level. In default mode it will serve as a regular 5-V/2-A power supply.

Since your PSV is designed to work with 5V/1500mA power input, it will work just fine with more powerful (2000mA) adapter. The concern about charging the battery "too quickly" is grossly unfounded for such a reputable manufacturer as Sony: all internal charger circuits have strict limits on how do they charge their internal battery, and this current will never increase under any input conditions.

As a bonus you will have a benefit of faster charging the battery **when playing**, as someone rightfully replied to you on Amazon, except the "ballooning" part.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up :) I now feel way safer using my Galaxy charger with my PS Vita. Just to confirm, there's not a chance that my Adaptive Fast Charger will ever supply the 9V charging level to the Vita because it will never ask for it, right?

Comment: @Itay080, QC uses a voltage level protocol on USB D+/D- wires for initial "handshake", and then the voltage-level request from a device. If this schema was not robust enough, Qualcomm would have serious liabilities in this world. So I guess it is safe enough.

Comment: "all internal charger circuits have strict limits on how do they charge their internal battery"  That's a good feature, someone should tell Apple.  I charged my iPhone with a tablet charger and my battery life dropped to about 10% of what it should be.  I'm no longer a fan of the quick charge.

Comment: @Misunderstood, yes, quick charge (aka "fast charge mode") does lead to a slightly less capacity and lesser useful charge-discharge cycles. But not to 10%. I guess the coloumb counting monitor in iPhone might need a better software, Apple is not above the law of labor outsourcing :-(